# Where I find telegram dataset?

Tags: dataset, social-networking

I want to analyze social network, thus I need to social network dataset. I want to telegram analyze but can not find dataset.
Where I find **telegram** dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [the repository with list of public datasets](https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets).

It is a part of a bigger list, called ["A curated list of awesome lists"](https://github.com/cdefgah/awesome).

It does not contain the telegram dataset, but contains many other datasets, that may help you with your endeavour.

Comment: Where I find telegram dataset or social network dataset with location data?

Comment: @HamidNadi I have no idea where to get telegram dataset. But, via link I provided in my answer, you can find datasets for variety of [social networks](https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets#social-networks).